# Is there any way to disable the code descriptions showing up on the autocompletion list performed by cmp plugin?

Tags: lua, neovim, nvim-lspconfig, nvim.cmp

I'm a newbie in Neovim and I've built my [almost overall configuration](https://github.com/DrShahinstein/dotfiles/tree/main/.config/nvim/custom) based on Nvchad.

And, here's an only thing that I could never find the way to change:

[image]

Notice the texts that I pointed out with yellow on the screenshot. I don't even know what those are called. Code "descriptions," I guess?

So, they remain a little bit of too much disturbing to me and I want to remove them. If I'm not mistaken, this must be something related to the cmp plugin although I read [doc/cmp.txt](https://github.com/hrsh7th/nvim-cmp/blob/main/doc/cmp.txt) and found nothing helpful. I also checked out [doc/lspconfig.txt](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/doc/lspconfig.txt) if this was related to lsp.

I would appreciate if anyone could teach me the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the trick. Here's my overall cmp.lua:

```
local lspkind = require "lspkind"
local default_options = require "plugins.configs.cmp"

local overriding_options = {
  completion = {
    keyword_length = 3,
  },
  performance = {
    max_view_entries = 7,
  },
  view = {
    docs = {
      auto_open = false,
    },
  },

  -- that's it
  formatting = {
    format = lspkind.cmp_format {
      before = function(_entry, vim_item)
        if vim_item.menu ~= nil and string.len(vim_item.menu) > 0 then
          vim_item.menu = string.sub(vim_item.menu, 1, 0) .. ""
        end
        return vim_item
      end,
    },
  },
}

local overall_options = vim.tbl_deep_extend("force", default_options, overriding_options)

return overall_options
```

And the result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The area highlighted in yellow is referred to as the Documentation window.
To customize its behavior, you can explore the available options documented in :help cmp-config.window.
For a specific solution, you can refer to the :help cmp-faq, particularly the section likely titled **How to disable the documentation window?**.

To disable the Documentation window, use the following Lua code in your Neovim configuration:

```lua
require"cmp".setup{
  -- Other configuration options here
  window = {
    documentation = cmp.config.disable
  }
  -- More configuration options here
}
```

Comment: I had actually tried that one before and it didn't do the trick.

Comment: Apparently this may have been something related to lsp